# .NET returning incorrect username

Tags: c#, .net, windows-authentication

I made a spelling mistake when I created an account a few weeks back. I changed the account and they can log onto the domain with the new name. However we have a web application in house that is still picking up the wrong name.

The .net application uses

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Which gives the old name.

If I use

```
Environment.UserName
```

I get the correct new name. What did I miss in the AD? Is there somewhere I can change the name which will result in System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; giving the correct name?

I have no experience with .net so I'm very sorry if the question has an obvious answer.

Comment: is there any chance it's cached in the web application / server?

Comment: Every user has two logon names: `User logon name` and `User logon name (pre-Windows 2000)`. Make sure you've corrected both.

Comment: That could very likely be the case. I'll try doing that in a few hours after the close of business (just in case anything goes wrong)

Comment: Other than that, the name _could_ be cached by the server. See [KB946358](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946358).

Comment: @Alex I have indeed. It does still seem the most logical explanation. The windows identity gives back the domain\username which is the pre-Windows 2000 logon name.. But I am looking at it as I type and the names match.

Comment: @Alex I've tried applying that fix but after restarting the DC there has been no change.. Any ideas?

Comment: @JenniferNolan You applied the fix to the web server, not the domain controller, right?

Comment: @Alex I applied it to the DC! Whoops! I'll apply it to the webserver there and see it that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Check out here for the Answer:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/27e42d4a-6452-4840-bbf2-abbc16e22557

Add the Key:

"HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/Lsa/LsaLookupCacheMaxSize=0"

To your registry as this is cached. I don't think restarting IIS will fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I tried that fix but its still giving the wrong user name.